# infinity geometric sum and series with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$$ for $r < 1$.

I know that I have to use induction but how do I start it?
I tried $k=1$ at first but it did not work so what should I do?

Comment: Minor note, you should have $|r| < 1$ (i.e. $-1 < r < 1$). Were $r$, say, $-2$, the result would be divergent. That aside I'm not sure how this would be proved inductively (at least directly), it doesn't seem quite a good fit. Maybe you could prove by induction that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Then from there, add the premise $|r| < 1$ and take the limit as $n \to \infty$ for both sides. The desired result would appear.

Comment: You can't do this by induction.  The set of $\{r \in \mathbb R| r<1\}$ can not be mapped to the natural numbers and $\infty$ is no a natural number.

Comment: By the way, this is not true if $r \le -1$.  So you need $|r| < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r^k = \frac 1{1-r}$ by induction.  $\infty$ is not a natural number.

But you can prove $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k = \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ by induction.

(Note: If $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k = \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} $ then $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} r^k=(\sum_{k=1}^n r^k) + r^{n+1} = \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} + r^{n+1} =  \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} + \frac {r^{n+1}(1-r)}{1-r}$)

(...or note that $(1-r)(1+r + r^2 + ....... + r^n) =?????????$)

But then you have

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^k = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.  BUt that is ONLY defined when the limit exists.

So you have to prove i) The limit exisits if $|r| < 1$ and ii) if $|r| < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} = \frac 1{1-r}$.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k = \frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ is true for any $r$ except $r=1$ and, if you write it in the form $(1-r)\sum_{k=1}^n r^k = 1-r^{n+1}$, it is true for any $r$ and $n$.

Comment: And, it you integrate the first equality in my comment above, you get the power series for log.